# Do triggers take a lot of computation?

Tags: sql, database

When implementing "Triggers" , is it required to check the criteria/condition for trigger WHENEVER a change is made? If it is so, can someone have a large number of triggers?

Or else, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers add overhead to the operation they are working on.  As with any other stored code, triggers can be made very complex and time consuming.  You generally want to avoid those.

Part of the issue with triggers is that they often old locks on tables/rows.  This can slow down other components of a query.

The number of triggers depends on the database.  Some limit to a single trigger per action per table.

In general, it is considered good practice to use other mechanisms if they can be used -- for instance, `NULL` constraints, `DEFAULT` values, and `CHECK` constraints.

I tend to avoid triggers because they are hard to maintain.  But there are well-designed, highly performant systems that do use them.

Comment: You can often specify which event triggers a trigger, e.g. in MySQL you can say that a trigger should be executed before/after a deletion, an insertion or an update. Sometimes you can even specify (also in the case of MySQL) that a trigger should be executed for each row or for each statement. So it can also be up to you how often a trigger gets called. But like gordon said, first try to figure out if it can be done with constraints or other mechanisms.